# How are Validation Messages transmitted from controller to view?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I needed to modify a Validation Message on a website. The reason is that (maybe is it bad) we took a shortcut. We are going to code a Custom ModelBinder. Still, I will expose my problem.

In the View file, we added several hidden input fields and using the Model Binder, in the controller, we gets two Entities (one is the model of the view file, the other one is created via the hidden input fields)

```
<input type="text"   name = "FromHiddenInputs.Name" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name ="FromHiddenInputs.Id" value="0" />
```

Note that FromHiddenInputs is not part of my @Model.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Entity MyModel, SecondEntity FromHiddenInputs)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid){
```

In Debug Mode on the method that deals with the posted result of my form. When I look at the ModelState, I see some validation errors for both entities.

So in the view file, using this code, I can display my validation message :

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyProperty)
```

or

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("FromHiddenInputs.Name", "*")
```

**So my question is the following, how does this Errors and Validation of the ModelState are passed from the ActionResult to the viewfile ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the validation process is performed earlier by the `ModelBinder`, the errors data already exists in `ModelState.Values`.

Now all that `ValidationMessageFor` helper method has to do is to extract the data from it's `ViewData.ModelState.Values` collection.

Answer (score 1):

The Model Validation messages are generated from the Model Properties and are generated by **jquery unobtrusive validation** without full postback but if you not include it, then full postback is done and messages generated by **jquery validate** js file.

In **jquery unobtrusive-validate.js** there is a method onError which is called when there is validation errorand it checks for each element and generates error message form Model Property and makes them visible.

Here is the method in **jquery-unobtrusive-validate.js** which is called:

```
function onError(error, inputElement) {  // 'this' is the form element
        var container = $(this).find("[data-valmsg-for='" + escapeAttributeValue(inputElement[0].name) + "']"),
            replace = $.parseJSON(container.attr("data-valmsg-replace")) !== false;

        container.removeClass("field-validation-valid").addClass("field-validation-error");
        error.data("unobtrusiveContainer", container);

        if (replace) {
            container.empty();
            error.removeClass("input-validation-error").appendTo(container);
        }
        else {
            error.hide();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where did the OP mention jQuery?

Comment: but the validation is done via jquery in asp.net mvc

Comment: That's optional and only client-side. The OP is talking server-side here.

Comment: but most of the time we do unobtrusive validation, no one wants to do postback for validating

Comment: You do, in the client-side. But upon submission, validation is performed in the server-side as well.

Comment: yes you are right, model is posted and then unobtrusive displays the messages